# Partial Specialization of tuple contents with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

Currently, I'm trying to get some code to react differently to different types. This isn't the exact code, but it gets the message across.

```
template<class A, class B>
struct alpha {
  enum { value = 0 };
};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct alpha<std::tuple<Args...>, T> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};

// This gets ignored
template<class T, class... Args>
struct alpha<std::tuple<Args..., std::vector<T> >, T> {
  enum { value = 2 };
};

// This gets ignored
template<class T, class... Args>
struct alpha<std::tuple<Args..., T>, T> {
  enum { value = 3 };
};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct alpha<T, std::tuple<Args...> > {
  enum { value = 4 };
};

template<class... LArgs, class... RArgs>
struct alpha<std::tuple<LArgs...>, std::tuple<RArgs...> > {
  enum { value = 5 };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << alpha<std::tuple<int, double>, double>::value << std::endl; // prints 1
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried more than this code shows, but nothing works so far and I ran across a problem with explicit specialization in a non-namespace scope. For reference, I'm working on gcc 4.6 (the one that comes with oneiric server), which I believe has complete variadic template support. I don't care how ugly it gets if the implementation works to detect the last argument of the parameter pack and the other types as well. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I wanted to share the solution I used based on the answers (this is an example).

```
template<typename T> struct tuple_last;

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct tuple_last<std::tuple<T,U,Args...>> {
  typedef typename tuple_last<std::tuple<U,Args...>>::type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct tuple_last<std::tuple<T>> {
  typedef T type;
};

namespace details {
// default case:
template<class T, class U>
struct alpha_impl {
enum { value = 1 };
};

template<class T>
struct alpha_impl<T, T> {
enum { value = 101 };
};

template<class T>
struct alpha_impl<T, std::vector<T>> {
enum { value = 102 };
};

// and so on.
}

template<class T, class... Args>
struct alpha<std::tuple<Args...>, T>
  : details::alpha_impl<T, tuple_last<std::tuple<Args...>>;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you compile using [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), it helpfully reports that (2) and (3) are unusable.  The warning for (3), which you expect to be selected, is as follows:

> warning: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
>
> ```
> struct alpha<std::tuple<Args..., T>, T> {
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> note: non-deducible template parameter '`Args`'
>
> ```
> template<class T, class... Args>
>                            ^
> ```

Why is `Args` not deducible?  The C++0x FDIS states at §14.8.2.5/9:

> If the template argument list of [a type that is specified in terms of template parameters] contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context.

In your specialization, the type `std::tuple<Args..., T>` is a type that is specified in terms of template parameters `Args` and `T`.  It contains a pack expansion (`Args...`), but that pack expansion is not the last template argument (`T` is the last template argument).  Thus, the entire template argument list of the `tuple` (the entirety of `<Args..., T>`) is a non-deduced context.

The argument list of the `std::tuple` is the only place in the template specialization's argument list that `Args` appears; since it is not deducible from there, it is not deducible at all and the specialization will never be used.

Matthieu M. [provides a clever workaround in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757691/partial-specialization-of-tuple-contents-with-variadic-arguments/6758377#6758377).

Comment: I don't know what the "solution" is or whether there is one at all.  There are others here who would know, though.

Comment: Well at least that tells me that there is no possible solution using this method, and lets me move on to others. If I come up with one that I like I'll post it.

Comment: Given that this is the issue, why not expand the pack on the left?

Comment: @dascandy: you cannot choose the `direction` of the expansion. The pack is either expanded or not, so I am not sure I follow your meaning :/

Comment: struct alpha<std::tuple<Args..., T>, T> | change to | struct alpha<std::tuple<T, Args...>, T>

Comment: @dascandy:  That doesn't do the same thing, though:  the OP's code tries to match a tuple where the _last_ argument is `T`; your code matches a tuple where the _first_ argument is `T`.

Comment: I don't think that " If an argument is a pack expansion, it shall be the last argument in the template argument list." applies here. You have two arguments in your argument list of the partial specialization - `std::tuple<Args..., T>` and `T`. Both aren't pack expansions. The `Args...` is an argument to a different argument list. Forbidding to mention `Args...` in *all* argumemt lists that appear within the argument list of a partial specialization doesn't make sense I think.

Comment: Consider: `template<typename X, typename A, typename B> struct SameWithX { static bool const value = false; }; template<template<typename ...> class L, typename X, typename ...A> struct SameWithX<X, L<A...>, L<A..., X>> { static bool const value = true; }; static_assert(SameWithX<int, tuple<char>, tuple<char, int>>::value, "lulz");` that's a completely sensible partial specialization. `A` is deduced in the second argument of the specialization. Then it is substituted into the third (where it appears in a non-deduced context according to 14.8.2.5p9 of the FDIS).

Comment: @Johannes:  `Args...` is not a pack expansion?  I understand that it is an argument to a different argument list, but 14.5.3/4 includes "pack expansions can occur...in a template argument list," so I was under the (possibly incorrect) impression that `Args...` is indeed a pack expansion.  I do think you are right that I was looking in the wrong section and that 14.8.2.5/9 is really where the answer is, in which case, "if the template argument list of P contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context."

Comment: @James `Args...` is a pack expansion. But `std::tuple<Args..., T>` is not.

Comment: @Johannes:  Oh, right.  I see what you're getting at then; I misunderstood.  In that case, I do think that that sentence from 14.8.2.5/9 in my above comment is what applies here.

Comment: @StackOverflow:  No, I do not wish to move this discussion to chat, but thank you for asking.

Answer (score 12):

@James provided the why, now let's try to find an alternative.

I would suggest using another level of indirection.

**1. Getting the last argument**

```
template <typename T> struct Last;

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct Last<std::tuple<T,U,Args...>>
{
  typedef typename Last<std::tuple<U,Args...>>::type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Last<std::tuple<T>>
{
  typedef T type;
};
```

**2. Introducing a specialized helper**

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct alpha_tuple
{
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template <typename T>
struct alpha_tuple<T,T>
{
  enum { value = 3 };
};

template <typename T>
struct alpha_tuple<std::vector<T>,T>
{
  enum { value = 2; }
};
```

**3. Hooking it up**

```
template <typename T>
struct alpha<std::tuple<>, T>
{
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template <typename T, typename U, typename Args...>
struct alpha<std::tuple<U, Args...>, T>
{
  typedef typename Last<std::tuple<U, Args...>>::type LastType;
  enum { value = alpha_tuple<LastType,T>::value };
};
```

Note that there is no last type for empty tuples, so I had to deal with them in a separate specialization.

Comment: Funny, I was about to do something extremely similar, trying to get the last argument. How do I give you both the right answer? I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Norcalli: it is impossible, you must choose one or the other. I would suggest you keeps James' as selected since he explained the problem you encountered (which is more general), and my answer is specifically tailored to your use case and thus present less interest to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to find out whether a tuple as a specific last member, here's a type trait for that:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename ...Args> struct back;
template <typename T, typename ...Args> struct back<T, Args...>
  { typedef typename back<Args...>::type type; };
template <typename T> struct back<T>
  { typedef T type; };


template <typename...> struct tuple_has_last : public std::false_type {};
template <typename T, typename... Args> struct tuple_has_last<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
  static const bool value = std::is_same<typename back<Args...>::type, T>::value;
};
```

*Edit:* Oh, I didn't see that Matthieu had already written the exact same thing. Never mind.